# Does PHP's flush() do anything if running from terminal/cli?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, flush

I'm starting php directly from the terminal and passing it a .php script to run, I'm not using a web browser.

The [documentation for flush()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) says

> Flushes the system write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is
> using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push current output
> all the way to the browser with a few caveats.

So based on that, it sounds possible that `flush()` could still be needed when you need output to immediately get sent to the terminal before the script ends, because of the part where it said "system write buffers of PHP". But I would like to know definitively. I'm using php 8.1 currently, but my question is hopefully not version specific.

I'm wanting to know from someone familiar with PHP's C implementation whether it ever under any circumstances buffers output when started from a terminal, or if that only happens if PHP is started a special way by a server. I know if I run code that intentionally requests buffering by using `ob_start()` or something like that, then it is supposed to buffer and this will not be ended by calling `flush()`, that's not what I'm asking about. I'm asking about code that doesn't explicitly request any buffering.

Comment: I guess I will just assume that it could buffer in the current and/or future versions of php based on how this sounds in the documentation. For CLI scripts that I really need to not buffer in that way, I will call ob_implicit_flush() at the start of the script so that I don't have to call flush() in my code and any other code my code is using won't need to call it either.

Answer (score 1):

Why not test that yourself?

```
<?php

// ob_start();

print "Test 1\n";
sleep(1);
print "Test 2";
sleep(5);
print "Test 3";
flush();
sleep(5);
```

On my test terminal (standard Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS), `ob_start` buffers *everything*, and ignores `flush()` altogether. Without `ob_start`, all text is output immediately (even if not ended by a LF, as is the case for the  second test).

I haven't a PHP 8.1 handy, but mine says,

```
> PHP 8.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2023 10:17:15) (NTS)
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.2.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

You might ask a *different* (opposite, even) question: *are there conditions whereby my terminal-run script might **start buffering** for some reason?*

When you call `flush()` the call gets ultimately redirected to sapi_module, which issues a fflush() on stdout (this on [the current source tree](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/output.c) on Github, but I don't think *this* was changed since at least PHP 5). This is enough, I believe, to say that `flush()` is *sufficient*.

Is it *necessary*? On a standard run from the terminal, *no*. But I didn't include any scriptlets or libraries or Composer modules that *might* have changed the buffering strategy.

Of course, any of those *could* have. Just issue an `ob_start()` (maybe because the module is born to run on a web server) and hey presto!, your script starts buffering and requires `flush` (actually, in that case, `ob_flush()` - as said above, `flush` will not work).

But if that's the case, you've got a completely different beast to deal with - you should probably write your own output function, so that all console writes are routed to some code that can check, say, `ob_get_level()` and deal with it accordingly. Or, bringing this to the extreme,

```
declare(ticks=1);
register_tick_function(static function() {
    ob_get_level() && ob_flush();
    flush();
});
```

Comment: With this simple test, it doesn't seem to be buffering. But this is far from definitive. I need someone familiar with PHP's C code to let me know if it ever buffers output when run from the terminal, or if that only happens when run in a special way by a server. I know that if I am running code that intentionally triggers buffering using ob_start() then it is supposed to buffer and that is unrelated to flush(). I'm asking about code that doesn't explicitly request any kind of buffering.

Comment: That's my point. **A simple test is all you need**. You said, "I'm starting php directly from the terminal and passing it a .php script to run". This is exactly what I've done.  However, I'm expanding on my answer

Comment: I'm more wondering about how print and echo work when php is started from the terminal with no special options. Do they ever trigger buffering other than in the case where some php code explicitly tried to instigate buffering. If the answer is no, why and how can it do this if run by a server? The documentation for flush made it sound like php could be doing its own buffering, potentially unrelated to ob_start() and similar functions.

Comment: You're right. Actually, from the documentation *I* had expected the output to be line buffered. I'm still quite baffled to see it isn't. Also, I haven't found where the buffering is turned off (as we can see it was). Stream buffering **is** unrelated to ob_start - the fact that ob ignores flush() is proof enough. **MAYBE** they turned off "normal" buffering altogether via vsetbuf() to avoid interference with the stream wrappers? (see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/docs/streams.md )

Comment: I guess I will just assume that it could buffer in the current and/or future versions of php based on how this sounds in the documentation. For CLI scripts that I really need to not buffer in that way, I will call ob_implicit_flush() at the start of the script so that I don't have to call flush() in my code and any other code my code is using won't need to call it either.